# Как в XMLHttpRequest добавить разные пути

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

После нажатия на одну из кнопок с уникальным id на одной странице, должны вызываться разные файлы.

Вот что я пробовал сделать.

```
<button id="x" onclick="loadWin()">Кнопка1</button>
<button id="y" onclick="loadWin()">Кнопка2</button>
<button id="z" onclick="loadWin()">Кнопка3</button>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>
function loadWin()
{
var x = document.getElementById('x');
var y = document.getElementById('y');
var z = document.getElementById('z');
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
x.xmlhttp.open("GET","windowx.php",true);
y.xmlhttp.open("GET","windowy.php",true);
z.xmlhttp.open("GET","windowz.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Еще пробовал сделать switch case в window.php, но вызвать нужный кейс не удалось.

Как после нажатия на кнопку вызвать указный файл?

Comment: Передать название файла параметром в функцию `function loadWin('fileName')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать значение не из id, а сразу в функцию:

```
<button onclick="loadWin("x")">Кнопка1</button>
<button onclick="loadWin("y")">Кнопка2</button>
<button onclick="loadWin("z")">Кнопка3</button>
```

в `function loadWin(t)` принимаем пришедшее значение, затем:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","window"+t+".php",true);
```

Следующий код уже соответственно не нужен:

```
var x = document.getElementById('x');
var y = document.getElementById('y');
var z = document.getElementById('z');
```

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то так.

Comment: Вы меня правильно поняли. Сделал. Спасибо!